# HeadSet, TailSet, SubSet in TreeSet

Tags: kotlin, treeset, sortedset

How does the relation between (headSet, TailSet, Subset) and TreeSet work? When you remove some elements from tree if this elements contains in Headset, TailSet or SubSet it will be removed in this sets. I want to make my own implementation of Binary Search Tree, and I want to know how this relation is works. Can someone please explain or give some resources where I can find information? This all I have:
interface:

```
import java.util.*
interface CheckableSortedSet<T> : SortedSet<T> {
    fun checkInvariant(): Boolean
}
```

class

```
    import java.util.*
    import kotlin.NoSuchElementException
    import java.util.TreeSet

class KtBinaryTree<T : Comparable<T>> : AbstractMutableSet<T>(), CheckableSortedSet<T> {

private var root: Node<T>? = null

override var size = 0
    private set

private class Node<T>(val value: T) {

    var left: Node<T>? = null

    var right: Node<T>? = null
}

override fun add(element: T): Boolean {
    val closest = find(element)
    val comparison = if (closest == null) -1 else element.compareTo(closest.value)
    if (comparison == 0) {
        return false
    }
    val newNode = Node(element)
    when {
        closest == null -> root = newNode
        comparison < 0 -> {
            assert(closest.left == null)
            closest.left = newNode
        }
        else -> {
            assert(closest.right == null)
            closest.right = newNode
        }
    }
    size++
    return true
}

override fun checkInvariant(): Boolean =
        root?.let { checkInvariant(it) } ?: true

private fun checkInvariant(node: Node<T>): Boolean {
    val left = node.left
    if (left != null && (left.value >= node.value || !checkInvariant(left))) return false
    val right = node.right
    return right == null || right.value > node.value && checkInvariant(right)
}

override fun remove(element: T): Boolean {
    var currentNode = root ?: return false
    var parentNode = root ?: return false
    var onRight = true
    while (currentNode.value != element) {
        parentNode = currentNode
        if (element > currentNode.value) {
            currentNode = currentNode.right ?: return false
            onRight = true
        } else if (element < currentNode.value) {
            currentNode = currentNode.left ?: return false
            onRight = false
        }
    }
    if (currentNode.left == null && currentNode.right == null) {
        //if removal point is leaf
        when {
            currentNode == root -> root = null
            onRight -> parentNode.right = null
            else -> parentNode.left = null
        }
    } else if (currentNode.left == null) {
        //if removal point have only right child
        if (currentNode == root) root = currentNode.right
        else {
            val right = currentNode.right ?: return false
            setNode(onRight, parentNode, right)
        }
    } else if (currentNode.right == null) {
        //if removal point have only left child
        if (currentNode == root) root = currentNode.left
        else {
            val left = currentNode.left ?: return false
            setNode(onRight, parentNode, left)
        }
    } else {
        //worst case - if removal point have both children
        var minNode = currentNode.right ?: return false
        var parentMinNode = currentNode.right ?: return false
        while (minNode.left != null) {
            parentMinNode = minNode
            val left = minNode.left ?: return false
            minNode = left
        }
        when {
            currentNode == root && parentMinNode == minNode -> {
                val rootLeft = root!!.left
                root = minNode
                minNode.left = rootLeft
            }
            currentNode == root && parentMinNode != minNode -> {
                parentMinNode.left = minNode.right
                root = minNode
                minNode.left = currentNode.left
                minNode.right = currentNode.right
            }
            parentMinNode == minNode -> setNode(onRight, parentNode, minNode)
            else -> {
                parentMinNode.left = minNode.right
                minNode.right = currentNode.right
                minNode.left = currentNode.left
                setNode(onRight, parentNode, minNode)
            }
        }
        minNode.left = currentNode.left
    }
    size--
    return true
}

private fun setNode(onRight: Boolean, parentNode: Node<T>, currentNode: Node<T>) {
    if (onRight)
        parentNode.right = currentNode
    else parentNode.left = currentNode
}

override operator fun contains(element: T): Boolean {
    val closest = find(element)
    return closest != null && element.compareTo(closest.value) == 0
}

private fun find(value: T): Node<T>? =
        root?.let { find(it, value) }

private fun find(start: Node<T>, value: T): Node<T> {
    val comparison = value.compareTo(start.value)
    return when {
        comparison == 0 -> start
        comparison < 0 -> start.left?.let { find(it, value) } ?: start
        else -> start.right?.let { find(it, value) } ?: start
    }
}

inner class BinaryTreeIterator : MutableIterator<T> {

    private var current: Node<T>? = null

    private fun findNext(): Node<T>? {
        val currentNode = current ?: return find(first())
        if (currentNode.value == last()) return null
        if (currentNode.right != null) {
            var successor = currentNode.right ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
            while (successor.left != null) {
                successor = successor.left ?: return successor
            }
            return successor
        } else {
            var successor = root ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
            var ancestor = root ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
            while (ancestor != currentNode) {
                if (currentNode.value < ancestor.value) {
                    successor = ancestor
                    ancestor = ancestor.left ?: return null
                } else ancestor = ancestor.right ?: return null
            }
            return successor
        }
    }

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = findNext() != null

    override fun next(): T {
        current = findNext()
        return (current ?: throw NoSuchElementException()).value
    }


override fun subSet(fromElement: T, toElement: T): SortedSet<T> =
        tailSet(fromElement).intersect(headSet(toElement)).toSortedSet()

override fun headSet(toElement: T): SortedSet<T> {
    val flag = this.contains(toElement)
    if (!flag) this.add(toElement)
    val setOfMax = mutableSetOf<T>()
    val iter = iterator()
    var element: T = iter.next()
    while (element != toElement) {
        if (!iter.hasNext()) throw IllegalArgumentException()
        setOfMax.add(element)
        element = iter.next()
    }
    if (!flag) this.remove(toElement)
    return setOfMax.toSortedSet()
}


override fun tailSet(fromElement: T): SortedSet<T> {
    val flag = !this.contains(fromElement)
    if (flag) this.add(fromElement)
    val setOfMax = mutableSetOf<T>()
    val iter = this.iterator()
    var element: T = iter.next()
    while (element != fromElement) {
        element = iter.next()
    }
    while (element != last()) {
        setOfMax.add(element)
        element = iter.next()
    }
    if (flag) this.remove(fromElement)
    setOfMax.add(element)
    return setOfMax.toSortedSet()
}

override fun first(): T {
    var current: Node<T> = root ?: throw NoSuchElementException()
    while (current.left != null) {
        current = current.left!!
    }
    return current.value
}

override fun last(): T {
    var current: Node<T> = root ?: throw NoSuchElementException()
    while (current.right != null) {
        current = current.right!!
    }
    return current.value
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found how i can do this i create a class to whom the same nodes will be given. And change iterator of this addtional tree that i called SubSet. this is changes in KtBinary tree:

```
override fun subSet(fromElement: T, toElement: T): SortedSet<T> =
            SubSet(this, fromElement, toElement)

override fun headSet(toElement: T): SortedSet<T> =
            SubSet(this, null, toElement)

override fun tailSet(fromElement: T): SortedSet<T> =
            SubSet(this, fromElement, null)
```

and this is SubSet(additional tree)

```
import java.util.*

class SubSet<T : Comparable<T>>(private val delegate: SortedSet<T>,
                                private val fromElement: T?,
                                private val toElement: T?) : AbstractMutableSet<T>(), SortedSet<T> {
    override fun comparator(): Comparator<in T>? = delegate.comparator()

    override fun subSet(fromElement: T, toElement: T): SortedSet<T> {
        return SubSet(this, fromElement, toElement)
    }

    override fun headSet(toElement: T): SortedSet<T> {
        return SubSet(this, null, toElement)
    }

    override fun tailSet(fromElement: T): SortedSet<T> {
        return SubSet(this, fromElement, null)
    }

    override fun last(): T {
        val iter = iterator()
        var element = iter.next()
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            element = iter.next()
        }
        return element
    }

    override fun first(): T {
        return iterator().next()
    }

    override fun add(element: T): Boolean {
        return when {
            fromElement == null && toElement == null -> false
            fromElement == null && element < toElement!! -> delegate.add(element)
            toElement == null && element >= fromElement!! -> delegate.add(element)
            element >= fromElement!! && element < toElement!! -> delegate.add(element)
            else -> false
        }
    }

    override fun remove(element: T): Boolean {
        return when {
            fromElement == null && toElement == null -> false
            fromElement == null && element < toElement!! -> delegate.remove(element)
            toElement == null && element >= fromElement!! -> delegate.remove(element)
            element >= fromElement!! && element < toElement!! -> delegate.remove(element)
            else -> false
        }
    }

    override fun iterator(): MutableIterator<T> = object : MutableIterator<T> {
        private val delegate = this@SubSet.delegate.iterator()

        private var next: T? = null

        init {
            while (delegate.hasNext()) {
                if (fromElement == null) {
                    this.next = delegate.next()
                    break
                }
                val next = delegate.next()
                if (next >= fromElement) {
                    this.next = next
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            val n = next ?: return false
            return n < toElement ?: return true
        }

        override fun next(): T {
            val result = next ?: throw NoSuchElementException()
            next = if (delegate.hasNext()) delegate.next() else null
            return result
        }

        override fun remove() {
            delegate.remove()
        }

    }

    override val size: Int
        get() = when {
            fromElement == null && toElement == null -> 0
            fromElement == null -> delegate.count { it < toElement!! }
            toElement == null -> delegate.count { it >= fromElement }
            else -> delegate.count { it >= fromElement && it < toElement }
        }
}
```

Comment: it work propperly. i have checked all possible variations